# Python Dataframe Complete Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one df dataframe as follow :

```
    Item       Notional
0   .decash    NaN
1   .decash    NaN
2    usdjpy    NaN
3   .decash    NaN
4    usdjpy    NaN
```

And a second df1 dataframe as follow:

```
    Item       Notional
0   .decash    10 000
1    usdjpy    100 000
```

Is that possible to fill df.Notional with df1.Notional without for instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [33]: df['Notional'] = df.Item.map(df1.set_index('Item').Notional)

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
      Item  Notional
0  .decash     10000
1  .decash     10000
2   usdjpy    100000
3  .decash     10000
4   usdjpy    100000
```

or:

```
In [36]: df.drop('Notional',1).merge(df1, on='Item', how='left')
Out[36]:
      Item  Notional
0  .decash     10000
1  .decash     10000
2   usdjpy    100000
3  .decash     10000
4   usdjpy    100000
```

Comment: Thx a lot @MaxU